# Overriding a SCSS mixin

Tags: sass

I'm trying to override a SCSS mixin which is a from a third party plugin. I don't want to edit the mixin directly so I created a copy of it and added all my modifications.

Currently the files are loaded in the following order:

```
@import "scss/button-mixin"; // Overridden 
@import "vendors/scss/button-mixin"; // Original
```

(in both files the mixin is named similarly)

I've also tried loading the overridden mixin after the original one but in both cases my custom overridden mixin simply ignored.

The same setup works in LESS but it's seems SCSS handling this in a different way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Sass Gist to help you visualise a mixin being overwritten, What you are trying to do should work. I would imagine that there is somewhere else that is causing the issue, could it possibly be the order that the mixin is being loaded by the plugin?

I can only suggest that you go through the sass start to finish step by step to resolve your issue.

[Example of mixin being overwritten](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/337e99ad2dd6cb6fb5820146e011706e)